# c++ Как обменять значениями две переменных

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Нужно написать программу, которая считывает значения двух целочисленных переменных `a` и `b`, затем меняет их значения местами (то есть в переменной `a` должно быть записано то, что раньше хранилось в `b`, а в переменной `b` записано то, что раньше хранилось в `a`). Затем вывести значения переменных.

Не знаю как обменять переменные значениями, символ `=` не помогает:

```
a = b;
b = a;
```

Но теперь в них обоих то же значение, которое было в `a` изначально.

---

От редактора:

Да, вопрос простой. Однако, он требует понимания того, как устроены переменные и как происходит присвоение значений переменных. Было бы ценно иметь ответ о том, почему одним взаимным присваиванием нельзя обменять переменные значениями.

Также, судя по комментариям, возможны альтернативные способы решения. Каждый из них добавит знаний о языке:

- Фактически тоже самое можно сделать и в C++, заключив левую и правую часть в список аргументов пары функций. –  Vlad from Moscow
- Можно было и без переменной, через xor. –  BOPOH

Если вы знаете альтернативный способ — пожалуйста, напишите ответ, по возможности снабдив его объяснением того, как и почему возможно такое решение.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что наряду с работой за автора это полнейшая профанация и нежелание что-то делать самому

Comment: Конечно не помогает, вам нужен обмен значений переменных, а не присвоение a=b.

Comment: В python может такое работать: `a, b = b, a`

Comment: @Wolkodav Фактически тоже самое можно сделать и в C++, заключив левую и правую часть в список аргументов пары функций.

Comment: Вопрос может быть и туп, но я только начал читать про c++. В интернете не нашел ответ на свои вопрос.

Comment: @werfghjkml: всё нормально, на мелочах мир держится. Вы, главное, учитесь и продолжайте вопросы задавать. И постарайтесь, пожалуйста,  в следующие вопросы добавить свой код, которым вы пытались решить задачу.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно, например, использовать дополнительную переменную, чтобы обменять значения двух других переменных. Это уже реализовано в стандарте языка C++ функцией `std::swap`

Но, как я понимаю, вам надо написать соответствующий код самостоятельно.

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    std::cout << "Enter two values: ";

    if ( std::cin >> a >> b )
    {
        std::cout << "The original values: a = " << a << ", b = " << b << std::endl;
        int tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
        std::cout << "After swapping: a = " << a << ", b = " << b << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {        
        std::cout << "Unexpected error occured" << std::endl;
    }     
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
Enter two values: 10 20
The original values: a = 10, b = 20
After swapping: a = 20, b = 10
```

EDIT: Я в своем комментарии к вопросу как раз имел в виду

```
std::tie( a, b ) = std::make_pair( b, a );
```

Другие способы - это, как я уже написал, использование другой стандартной функции

```
std::swap( a, b );
```

Или можно еще использовать новую функцию `std::exchange`

Вот демонстрационная программа, которая показывает использование этих стандартных функций

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 20;

    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << std::endl;

    std::tie( a, b ) = std::make_pair( b, a );

    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    a = 10, b = 20;

    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << std::endl;

    std::swap( a, b );

    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    a = 10, b = 20;

    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << std::endl;

    std::exchange( a, std::exchange( b, a ) );

    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
a = 10, b = 20
a = 20, b = 10

a = 10, b = 20
a = 20, b = 10

a = 10, b = 20
a = 20, b = 10
```

Comment: Думаю, раз есть готовая функция `std::swap`, то можно и ее смело использовать. Постановке задачи соответствует. :)

Answer (score 8):

Можно сделать в стиле Python-овского `a, b = b, a`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(b, a);
  std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
}
```

В случае 2-х переменных это конечно перебор, т.к. есть swap, но в случае бОльшего количества переменных такая конструкция может оказаться полезной. Как пример, циклическая перестановка четырех переменных:

```
std::tie(a, b, c, d) = std::make_tuple(b, c, d, a);
```

Comment: `std::tie`? Не знал, круто.

Answer (score 2):

Меня однажды спросили об этом на собеседовании, я предложил 2 способа.

xor:

```
a ^= b ^= a ^= b;
```

сложение и вычитание:

```
a += b;
b = a - b;
a -= b;
```

Comment: Стоит добавить, что способ с xor не работает, если `&a == &b`. Или в более сложном случае, если `a` и `b` занимают _перекрывающиеся_ области памяти. (Впрочем, эта вторая ситуация вероятно UB из-за strict alisasing rule).

Comment: А второй вариант работает только для unsigned-, но не signed-типов, потому что переполнение signed-типа — UB.

Comment: @VladD  "способ с xor не работает," а как адрес может быть одинаковым? Вы имеете в виду `union`? Или если `a` и `b` - ссылки?

Comment: Ну, например, так: http://pastebin.com/SxXmAKST

Comment: Или там `a` может быть подставлено макросом, который при некоторых условиях раскрывается в `b`. Или ещё как-нибудь.

Comment: Или у вас есть два указателя на объекты: `xor_swap(p1->x, p2->x)`, и случайно в силу логики программы они у вас укажут на один и тот же объект.